# Issue in placing view in FooterTableViewCell in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, admob

I have a table view in which there is a footer view cell. I have a view in the footer table view cell class. In my VC class where I'm calling delegate for the footer cell, I'm passing my Admob view to that view but it isn't showing my ads on it. How can I show my ads on that view? This is my FooterCell class code:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GADBannerView *adView;
```

This is my VC class where I'm getting this view,

```
- (nullable UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    FooterTVCell *footerTVCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FooterTVCell"];
        //Admob Banner
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 450, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 70)];
    bannerView_.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"; //change this key
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    //request.testDevices = @[ @"326e918015806f8d65a43e86f9e6e939" ];
    request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];
    NSLog(@"%@", request.testDevices);
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    bannerView_.delegate = self;

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25);
    // [button setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(goToFun) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [bannerView_ addSubview:button];

    [footerTVCell.adView addSubview:bannerView_];
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:request];

    return footerTVCell;
}
```

This is my view when i run the app,
[image]

Comment: Is your device online, is the request working?

Comment: ads are coming fine but not on the view that i want.@Koen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the y position you mentioned.

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, **450**, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 70)];
```

Check it in Debug view Hierarchy tool in Xcode. Also if you have only one section, make as adman view as tableview.footerview in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Please properly format your answer by using code blocks

Comment: y should be 0, not 450.

Comment: It was spotted by @Fisky, so go ahead and accept the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed adding another delegate which is required as per the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614946-tableview).

> This method only works correctly when
>   tableView(_:heightForFooterInSection:) is also implemented.

You need to implement that method too for this to work.

Comment: i have also added that but my view is not showing my ads view which is bannerView_ . @Ruchira Randana